# How do you find singular solutions to first order differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

How do you find singular solutions to differential equations? for example I am working with the equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\cos^2(x)$$ This is a very easy separable equation. For some reason by intuition:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=0 \to y\cos^2(x)=0$$

we have solutions at $y=0$ and $\cos^2(x)=0$

Am I on the right track. Is this justified how?

Comment: The point is that when you solve a separable equation $y'=f(x) g(y)$, you divide by $g(y)$, which you can only do if $g(y) \neq 0$. This process "kills" any solutions $y \equiv y_0$ where $g(y_0)=0$, so all of those solutions have to be re-introduced separately.

Comment: I get that. So then y=0 is a singular solution but cos^2(x) = 0 which is at 1 is not a singular solution?

Comment: $x$ can't be constrained by the solution like $y$ can; each $x$ in some suitable domain needs a corresponding value of $y$. $\cos^2(x)=0$ doesn't allow you to pick $y$ that way.

Answer (score 0):

By separing variable $$\frac {dy}y= cos^2 x dx$$ Then integrating you obtain $$ ln |y| = \frac 12 (sen x cos x + x)$$
Finally you have $$y=\pm e^{\frac 12 (sen x cos x + x)}$$

Comment: Yeah I already got that answer but I think the only singular solution is y=0?

Comment: actually you are wrong $$\int cos^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}cos(2x)$$ Which gives $\frac{1}{2} \int cos(2x) = \frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}sin(2x)$