# Are there multiple ways to solve the integral $\int \cos^2(x)dx$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Both with the internet, places like wolfram and symbolab and in a previous question: [How do you find singular solutions to first order differential equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3334235/how-do-you-find-singular-solutions-to-first-order-differential-equations)

I get different answers for the integral I am working on an ODE with $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\cos^2(x)$$

after separation on the RHS: $$\int \cos^2(x)dx$$

Now I get two answers:

1) $\frac{1}{2} \sin(x)\cos(x)+x$

Now the way I solved it was by doing substitution:

$$\int \cos^2(x) = \int \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)$$

Integrating and subbing u for 2x: $$\frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)$$

general formula is $$y=e^{\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)+c}=Ce^{\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)}$$

Comment: You have integrated $\cos^2 x$ incorrectly. Remember $\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}$.

Comment: Did you mean $\dfrac12\left(\sin x\cos x + x\right)$ and $\dfrac12x+\dfrac14\sin 2x $?

Comment: Yes I thought they were different meaning that one of the answers was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is $\frac{1}{2} \big( \sin (x) \cos (x) + x\big)$ and note that, since $\sin (2\theta)= 2\sin(\theta) \cos (\theta)$, the other answer you got (with the exception that you had a small sign mistake) is also correct :
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{4}\sin(2x) &= \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{4}\big( 2\sin (x) \cos (x) \big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}\sin (x) \cos (x) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \big( x + \sin (x) \cos (x) \big)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please include the constant of integration. I would basically consider the answer incorrect without it as different methods can give apparently different forms, which actually differ only by a constant.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is not the case and I did it only to realize that they are *exactly* the same.